# Add/loop multiple videos, player names and events via YouTube API dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

I'm trying to make an array of players to pass to new YT.Player. I keep getting 'player1' undefined, and the iFrame never gets added to the stated 'playerInfo.id'.

My code, without player2 or player3 included for simplicity:

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var playerInfoList = [
{playerName: 'player1', id: 'container1', videoId: 'WPvGqX-TXP0', eventId: 'playerOneReady'},
{playerName: 'player2', id: 'container2', videoId: 'Yj0G5UdBJZw', eventId: 'playerTwoReady'},
{playerName: 'player3', id: 'container3', videoId: '9gTw2EDkaDQ', eventId: 'playerThreeReady'}]; 

var players = new Array();

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    if (typeof playerInfoList === 'undefined') return;

    for (var i = 0; i < playerInfoList.length; i++) {
        var generatePlayers = createPlayer(playerInfoList[i]);
        players[i] = generatePlayers;
    }
}

function createPlayer(playerInfo) {
    playerInfo.playerName = new YT.Player(playerInfo.id, {
        height: '390',
        width: '640',
        videoId: playerInfo.videoId,
        events: {
            'onReady': playerInfo.eventId
        }
    });
}

// When the Players are ready.
var duration1;

function playerOneReady() {
    duration1 = player1.getDuration();
}

function play(playerNum) {
    playerNum.seekTo(0);
    playerNum.playVideo();
}

$('#player1-trigger').click(function(){
   play(player1);
}
```

I'm not sure why it keeps coming back as undefined. I have a simpler structure that works fine, but it involves adding each player manually, and I'm trying to make it more dynamic/efficient. Although this is more efficient than dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

from what i'm seeing you made a mistake in the function createPlayer. while you're trying to make a player with the name player1 you're actually saving the new YT.player on the location of playerInfo.playername. it would be better to save in te players list directly like this:

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
 if (typeof playerInfoList === 'undefined') return;

 for (var i = 0; i < playerInfoList.length; i++) {
     var generatePlayers = createPlayer(playerInfoList[i],i);
 }
}

function createPlayer(playerInfo, locationInList) {
players[locationInList] = new YT.Player(playerInfo.id, {
    height: '390',
    width: '640',
    videoId: playerInfo.videoId,
    events: {
        'onReady': playerInfo.eventId
    }
});
}
```

and then when calling for the players use:

```
$('#player1-trigger').click(function(){
 play(players[1]);
}
```

For the future I would suggest when making code more efficient/dynamic/readable to make multiple smaller changes and to test after every change if the code still works. That way it's easier to find what has broken.

Comment: This isn't working for me. The iFrame is still not being added to the div stated in id: 'container1', and my eventId: 'playerOneReady' is never being called. It's strange, because it's very simple code...

Comment: if (typeof playerInfoList === 'undefined') return; I checked this in the console, and my playerInfoList is undefined @zirrak